# How do I handle POST data in Express.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, express

I am currently consistently getting 500 errors from Express.js that I believe hinge on a failure to obtain a string key that the request hinges on.

On the client side, I have several requests hitting the same point (`/restore`), all of which are intended to make "key" a field in a jQuery.ajax() call's `data` dictionary, included in turn in the main dictionary. On the client-side, I have the following, which includes localStorage fallback that I don't think is particularly relevant:

```
var restore = function(key, default_value, state, callback)
  {
  populate_state(state, default_value);
  state.initialized = false;
  var complete = function(jqxhr)
    {
    if (jqxhr.responseText === 'undefined')
      {
      }
    else
      {
      populate_state(state, JSON.parse(jqxhr.responseText));
      }
    callback();
    state.initialized = true;
    }
  jQuery.ajax('/restore',
    {
    'complete': complete,
    'data':
      {
      'key': key,
      'userid': userid
      },
    'method': 'POST',
    });
  if (Modernizr.localstorage)
    {
    if (localStorage[key] === null || localStorage[key]
      === undefined)
      {
      return default_value;
      }
    else
      {
      return JSON.parse(localStorage[key]);
      }
    }
  else
    {
    return default_value;
    }
  }

  restore('Calendar', default_value,
    default_value, function()
    {
    jQuery('#submit-calendar').prop('disabled', false);
    });

    restore('Scratchpad', '', result, function()
      {
      for(var instance in CKEDITOR.instances)
        {
        if (CKEDITOR.instances[instance])
          {
          CKEDITOR.instances[instance].setReadOnly(false);
          }
        }
      });

    return restore('Todo', {
      'items': [],
      'text': ''
      },
      {
      'items': [],
      'text': ''
      },
      function()
        {
        jQuery('#add-activity-button').prop('disabled', false);
        jQuery('#todo-new-entries').prop('disabled', false);
        });

  return restore('YouPick', {
    start_time: new Date().getTime()
    },
    {
    start_time: new Date().getTime()
    },
    function()
      {
      });
```

Note that each call to restore() explicitly specifies a nonempty, unique, alphabetic string for the key as the first argument.

On the server side, Express's routes/index.js has a view that is servicing the request:

```
router.post('/restore', function(request, response, next)
  {
  console.log('router.post /restore');
  console.log('Query: ' + request.query);
  console.log('href: ' + sanitize(request.user.href));
  console.log('key: ' + sanitize(request.query.key));
  var result = look_up_key(request.user.href, request.query.key);
  console.log(result);
  response.type('application/json');
  response.send(result);
  });
```

The sanitize function wipes out characters that are not alphanumeric or an explicitly enumerated punctuation character. It should have no request on the purely alphabetic key.

This, with the multiple calls, has an output for /bin/www of:

```
router.post /restore
Query: [object Object]
href: httpsapi.stormpath.comv1accounts**********************
POST /restore 500 39.516 ms - 1210
router.post /restore
Query: [object Object]
href: httpsapi.stormpath.comv1accounts**********************
POST /restore 500 5.000 ms - 1210
router.post /restore
Query: [object Object]
href: httpsapi.stormpath.comv1accounts**********************
POST /restore 500 5.842 ms - 1210
```

It looks like there is something there for the query, but where do I access it? http://expressjs.com/api.html seems like I should be able to treat it as a dictionary, but among the server-side console.log() calls, `console.log('key: ' + sanitize(request.query.key));` does not appear to be producing any output, even an empty or corrupt key. It appears to crash there, apparently sending a 500 from there.

I could probably, or at least possibly, circumvent the issue by encoding and decoding data as JSON, and while I think that's generally a winning solution, I would like to understand why this is not working.

I also don't think that `key` is someone's reserved word; a global, hand-inspected search and replace from `key` to `identifier` seemed not to observably alter the behavior.

So two questions, in order of preference:

1: How can I send and receive variables that will be interpreted as putting things into a GET or POST query string, or taking them out of the same? And what is the `[Object object]` represented by request.query?

2: If that's not the route to take, and I should just use JSON, what (if anything) should I know about JSON encoding in this exact context? Is it as simple as JSON is normally, or are there things I should be advised of?

Thanks,

Comment: You should log errors to get a clue why the 500 happens exactly. If you pass `request.query` as separate argument to `console.log()` (`console.log('Query: ', request.query)`) you would see it's most likely an empty object, because with `POST` requests you need to use `request.body` (which also requires using [`body-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser)).

Comment: @robertklep Thank you; please restate your comment in an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 0):

With `POST` requests, data is usually passed in the request body, which means that you need to use `req.body` instead of `req.query` (the latter is used to access the data passed in the query string of a URL). Before `req.body` works, you need to include the [`body-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) middleware.

As for why `[object Object]` is being logged: this has to do with stringification. Your log command uses `+` to "add" a string and an object (`request.query`), which will use the string representation of an object and that happens to be `[object Object`].

Instead, you should pass objects are separate arguments to `console.log()`:

```
console.log('Query: ', request.query); // comma instead of plus
```

That will show a more elaborate string representation of the object. Alternatively, you can even have it print out as JSON:

```
console.log('Query: %j', request.query)
```